# Solr - Index MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, solr

Is it possible index a complete database without mentioning the table names explicitly in the data-config.xml as new tables are added everyday and I cannot change the data-config.xml everyday to add new tables.

Comment: How do you determine the current name of the table? You'd probably be best off by creating a data-config.xml template, then replacing the table name before starting the import process. If you're on a *nix-variant, you'd probably do this by using date and replace in bash.

Comment: the names of the table are based on date like abcd_2011_03_19. I dont want to do that manually as once I deploy the project I wont have access to the files

Answer (score 0):

Haven table names based on the date smells like there is something wrong in your Design. But given this requirement in your question you can add Data to your solr server without telling you have a DB. You just have to make sure you hav a unique ID for the data record in you solr Server with whom you can identify the corresponding record in your DB, something like `abcd_2011_03_19.uniqueid`. You can post the data to solr in Java in solrj or just plain xml or json.

Example:

```
--------------
| User Input |
--------------
      |post
      V
-----------------------------------
| My Backend (generate unique id) |
-----------------------------------
  |post(sql)       |post (e.g. solrj)
  V                V
------           --------
| DB |           | solr |
------           --------
```

My ascii skillz are mad :D

Comment: Could you shed some more light on this Moritz as I am not able to completely understand what you wanted to say. Oh and mad ASCII skills indeed :P